# Transfer audio across VNC or SSH

Tags: ssh, vnc

I've got a program that says what you type, I tried it directly on the raspberry pi and worked perfectly but when I use it across a VNC server on my windows PC I can't hear what it says.
Is it that you can't transfer audio across VNC?
Then when I try it through SSH it also doesn't work.
Then I try it directly from the raspberry pi and It doesn't work.
Please help, it's not just for this program but it also is if in a future I make more complex programs and can't do it on my windows pc.
Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use PulseAudio on your Pi and your target machine. There are [binaries for Windows](http://www.cendio.com/pulseaudio/) available.

Your setup would look like this:

1. Make sure the Pi is running pulseaudio
2. Install PulseAudio on Windows
3. SSH to the Pi (possibly also install a [Windows X11 server](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/))
4. Tell the X11 clients to [use the PulseAudio server on your Windows](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Examples#Switching_the_PulseAudio_server_used_by_local_X_clients) host.

This should also work with the VNC solution. The X11 solution may be faster and nicer looking, but the VNC also has its merits (most notably that you can dis- and re-connect).

Comment: So you use the Pi as a audio server and then you use the windows X11 server/client to acces the audo no?

Comment: You don't tell the X11 server (the xming program on Windows, or X.org on the Pi), but rather the X11 clients (whatever programs you are running, e.g. your text to speech software [TTS]) to use the pulseaudio sink on your Windows machine. If the TTS is a command line program, you may need to use pactl to set the output, or tell the TTS program itself. (Also check out this Q&A: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65246/change-pulseaudio-input-output-from-shell)

Comment: Nov 2017 - Point #4 - The link now points to a product called ThinLinc.  PulseAudio for Windows is now supported by OpenSUSE at https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Ports/Windows/Support/